# Only allowing selection of one radio button in a form with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

A very basic question...

How can I only allow the selection of one option in a list of radio buttons?

```
<form action="process_repair.php" method="POST">
    <label for "repair_complete">Repair complete</label>
    <input type="radio" name="Yes" value="true">
    <input type="radio" name="No" value="false">
</form>
```

When this code runs, it's possible to select both radio buttons, but I'd like them to interact so you can only select one or the other.

Any help much appreciated! :)

Comment: Give all the same name `name="repairgroup"`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Give them the same name.

```
<form action="process_repair.php" method="POST">
 Repair complete
 <input type="radio" name="complete" value="true" id="complete_yes" />
 <label for="complete_yes">Yes</label>
 <input type="radio" name="complete" value="false" id="complete_no" />
 <label for="complete_no">No</label>
</form>
```

Labels must have a `for` attribute, directing to the corresponding input's `id`.

Comment: You can also just do <label><input ...> Label text</label>.

Comment: Do note that the implicit linking (comment above) is deprecated as of XHTML 1.1(?).

Comment: @antennen I can't see any mention of that in the XHTML 1.1 spec, but implicit labeling doesn't enjoy as wide support as with the for attribute.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out (given the question) that the "select one radio in a group" is a function of HTML, not PHP. You just need to assign them all to the same group (by giving them the same name).

Answer (score 2):

Every input should have same "name"